# factory girl association with a children class, show nomethoderror: undefined method

Tags: associations, factory-bot, nomethoderror

```
file 1 . user.rb

factory :user do
  name  "test"
end

factory :admin_user, :parent => user do
  role  "admin"
end

file 2. manager.rb

factory :manager do
  association :admin_user
  description "manager"
end

and while run FactoryGirl.create(:manager), it will show NoMethodError:
       undefined method `admin_user=' for #<Manager ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glancing at the factorygirl [wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md), it looks to me like you need to change your manager.rb code to:

```
factory :manager do
  association :user, :factory => :admin_user
  description "manager"
end
```